# Static linking SSL with Poco

Tags: c++, ssl, linker, poco

I'm trying to build dll with static linking Poco library which require OpenSSl.

When I build Poco library with static linking with *libeay32MDd.lib* and *ssleay32MDd.lib* it works good but require OpenSSL's DLLs. If I use *libeay32MTd.lib* and *ssleay32MTd.lib*, it throws the following errors :

> libeay32MTd.lib(e_capi.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __imp_CertOpenStore referenced in function capi_open_store
>   8>libeay32MTd.lib(e_capi.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __imp_CertCloseStore referenced in function capi_find_key
>   8>libeay32MTd.lib(e_capi.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore referenced in function
>   capi_find_cert 8>libeay32MTd.lib(e_capi.obj) : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFindCertificateInStore referenced
>   in function capi_find_cert 8>libeay32MTd.lib(e_capi.obj) : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp_CertDuplicateCertificateContext referenced in function capi_load_ssl_client_cert 8>libeay32MTd.lib(e_capi.obj) : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateContext
>   referenced in function capi_find_key 8>libeay32MTd.lib(e_capi.obj) :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp_CertGetCertificateContextProperty referenced in function capi_cert_get_fname

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to link with crypt32.lib

Comment: This is correct. An extra note: crypt32.lib is a Windows built-in library, so don't worry (as I did!) if you don't see it in the compiled results of building OpenSSL.